# node.js | mongodb connection error "callstack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

### MongoDB and Node.js Issue

---

so.. i'm pretty new to `mean-stack` and keep learing. but for some reason i'm unable to understand why i keep getting the error..

```
{ [MongoError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]
   name: "MongoError",
   message: "Maximum call stack size exceeded" }
```

as soon as i'm trying to connect to the database instance running with..

```
> mongod --port 2016 --dbpath C:\Users\Me\OneDrive\Concepts\Node\db
```

through this pretty decent piece of code..

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient
var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:2016/db_name";

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log("connected");

    db.close();
});
```

the connection will hold on for arround 5-10 seconds and cut off giving me the above error.

i already tried to run another db instance out of `OneDrive` but wasn't successful, as well as connecting through different features, like..

```
new MongoClient(new Server("localhost", 2016)); /* ... */
```

all unsuccessful. I would appreciate some useful solutions on that.
**Thanks** in advance.

---

#### Edit

> Which version of mongodb am i using?

```
{
    "name": "mongodb",
    "version": "2.0.46",
    ...
```

> Which version of mongoose am i using?

Am i using mongoose? I don't know. My current solution is to call the `MongoClient.connect(...)` method.

Comment: which version of mongoose are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally came up using `mongoose` package to connect to the database. All works fine now, still don't know what exactly caused this error but whatever..

`/closed`